# Wait for user's response in Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm creating a simple permissions system. I need to send a request via Socket.IO and user just sending a response with true (accept) or false (deny).

On this time I've:

```
socket.on('initModule', function (out) {
   io.sockets.in('permissions').emit('permissionRequest', {
      uniqid : out.appid,
      // Something goes here, no one really cares.
   });
});

socket.on('permissionReturn', function(output){ 
   if(output.status)
      module.exports.modules[out.module](out.data, function(res){
         if(res.status == "ok")
            sendResponse(socket, out.module, 'ok', res.response);
         else if(res.status == 'error')
            sendResponse(socket, out.module, 'error', res.response);
      });
   else
      sendResponse(socket, out.module, 'error', "Not permitted");
});
```

In 'permissionReturn' event I've a "out" variable, but it's in 'initModule'. While I'm creating a global variable for move it, it's returns undefined. When I move 'permissionReturn' event to 'initModule', it's just doesn't works. Sending variable via socket.io and read via event is unsecure. So...how can I fix that?

Comment: Can you state exactly what your question is?

Comment: A 'initModule' event runs something what needs a permission from user. My question is - what can I get return in it from another event. Sure it's weird but I'm thinking you understand what i want to do.